# Installation errors: Overwrite Akeneo ProductController

Tags: php, symfony, akeneo

I want to overwrite the `ProductController` from the `EnrichBundle`.

Everything works in the dev mode, but when I want to install it on our production server with `php app/console pim:install --env=prod --force` I get errors and the Akeneo is not working:

```
Load "Title Templates" from annotations and config files to db
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
Title for route "pim_enrich_attributegroup_index" could not be saved. Route not found.

oro:navigation:init
The command terminated with an error code: 1.
```

The installation works, if I uncomment the `getParent()` method in `MyEnrichBundle`, but then my `ProductController` doesn't work anymore.

```
class MyEnrichBundle extends Bundle
{

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'PimEnrichBundle';
    }

}
```

What can I do to avoid these ORO installation errors?

Comment: Can you please explain the steps of overriding productController from the EnrichBundle (/Pim/Bundle/EnrichBundle/Controller/Rest/productController)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We changed this route key recently on the current development branch so your problem seems to be related to that. I recommend you to use only tagged versions of the PIM (last released version [here](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/releases)) to be sure to have a stable installation.

An other important information: The only difference between an installation in prod environment (`-e=prod`) and in dev environment (`-e=dev`) is the cache warmup. So you can safely install your PIM on your production server in dev mode and then use it in production.

To fix your problem, I recommend you to update your dependencies (if you are using our enterprise edition) with composer :

`php composer.phar update`

After that you can clear your cache manually with

`rm -rf ./app/cache/*`

And then install Akeneo PIM in dev mod:

`php app/console pim:install --force -e=dev`

Comment: Thanks for this bunch of useful information, I will accept it as answer. Although after hours of debugging I realized that my problem is something else: After renaming the file `Resources/config/routing.yml` in `MyEnrichBundle` to `routing2.yml` (and fixing my reference in `app/config/routing`), the installation errors disappeared. As a Symfony/Akeneo beginner I don't know why, but I'm happy everything works now :-).